# Deciding if sets are bounded and/or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How do we find out if a given set is bounded or closed?

1) $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 : x^2+2y^2-3z^3=1\}$

2) $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : |x|+2|y|+3|z|\le 1\}$

3) $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=9\} 
\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : y=3\}$

Comment: Is $\mathbb R$ bounded? is a union of an unbounded set with any other set bounded? This will help you with (3).

Answer (score 1):

For a continuous function $f: \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$, its level sets
$$M_\alpha := \{y \in \mathbb R^n | f(y) = \alpha\}$$
as well as the sets
$$N_\alpha^+ := \{y\in \mathbb R^n | f(y) \ge \alpha\}\\
N_\alpha^- := \{y\in\mathbb R^n | f(y) \le \alpha\}$$
are closed. A finite union of closed sets remains closed.

For boundedness, try to find $\sup_{y\in A} \|y\|$ in a suitable norm. If you can prove it is finite, the set is bounded. If it's infinite, the set $a$ is unbounded.

In your case you can find sequences with $\|y_n\|_\infty \to\infty$ fairly easy for sets $A$ and $C$, and for set $B$, you can show that $\|y\|_1 \le 1$ easily as well.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for correcting the mistake, but next time please use a comment to notify about the mistake. Edits are not intended for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that edits are solely intended to improve posts! :) Of course, a comment wouldn't hurt but it seemed pretty clear in this case.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Technically the edit changed the meaning of the post, wich is not to be done without further notice. This is not a great deal in this case, but in other cases, it might become one.

Comment: I think you mean "level sets."  I've never heard of niveau sets, but niveau is French for level.

Comment: @SpamIAm It is german for level as well; thanks for pointing out.